# How to get the index path of found values using jq?

Tags: jq

Say I have a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "json": [
    "a", 
    [
      "b", 
      "c", 
      [
        "d", 
        "foo", 
        1
      ], 
      [
        [
          42, 
          "foo"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

And I want an array of `jq` index paths that contain `foo`:

```
[
    ".json[1][2][1]",
    ".json[1][3][0][1]"
]
```

Can I achieve this using `jq` and how?
I tried `recurse | .foo` to get the matches first but I receive an error: `Cannot index array with string "foo"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure what is the purpose of obtaining an array of `jq` programs. While means of doing this exist, they are seldom necessary; jq does not provide any sort of `eval` command.

jq has the concept of a path, which is an array of strings and numbers representing the position of an element in a JSON; this is equivalent to the strings on your expected output. As an example, `".json[1][2][1]"` would be represented as `["json", 1, 2, 1]`. The standard library contains several functions that operate with this concept, such as `getpath`, `setpath`, `paths` and `leaf_paths`.

We can thus obtain all leaf paths in the given JSON and iterate through them, select those for which their value in the input JSON is "foo", and generate an array out of them:

```
jq '[paths as $path | select(getpath($path) == "foo") | $path]'
```

This will return, for your given input, the following output:

```
[
  ["json", 1, 2, 1],
  ["json", 1, 3, 0, 1]
]
```

Now, although it should not be necessary, and it is most likely a sign that you're approaching whatever problem you are facing in the wrong way, it is possible to convert these arrays to the jq path strings you seek by transforming each path through the following script:

```
".\(map("[\(tojson)]") | join(""))"
```

The full script would therefore be:

```
jq '[paths as $path | select(getpath($path) == "foo") | $path | ".\(map("[\(tojson)]") | join(""))"]'
```

And its output would be:

```
[
  ".[\"json\"][1][2][1]",
  ".[\"json\"][1][3][0][1]"
]
```

Comment: Wrong approach to the problem or not, this answer has helped get a much better understanding of how jq works. Thank you! :)

Comment: to get just the paths, one per line without any json stuff in it:
jq -C  '[paths as $path | select(getpath($path) == "ValueToSearchFor") | $path] | ".\(map("[\(tojson)]") | join(""))"' | jq -r '.[] | "."+join(".")'

Answer (score 3):

Santiago's excellent program can be further tweaked to produce output in the requested format:

```
def jqpath:
  def t: test("^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$");
  reduce .[] as $x
    ("";
     if ($x|type) == "string"
     then . + ($x | if t then ".\(.)" else  ".[" + tojson + "]" end)
     else . + "[\($x)]"
     end);

[paths as $path | select( getpath($path) == "foo" ) | $path | jqpath]


jq -f wrangle.jq input.json

[
  ".json[1][2][1]",
  ".json[1][3][0][1]"
]
```